# how to authorize google picker with oauth2 token from app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-picker

I am developing an App Engine Java program that uses OAuth2 at login. In other words, user must give approval before using the app.  I now want to integrate Google Picker functionality without having to authenticate (request permission again) on the client.

What I've done was pass an object(loginInfo is a json object) with the token as a property.

While the token works perfectly fine on the server side, on the client I am getting an UnAuthorized 401 error. 
**EDIT**
I should mention that the scope on the server side includes all the necessary permissions for the Views on the Picker and that my Picker Api is enabled as well as the Drive API.

My question is now, what would be the best way to handle this situation? Is it even safe to post authToken on the client? How can I achieve this scenario so that the user doesn't approve twice and still use Picker? Are there better solutions than Picker for upload to Drive, Picassa, or other Google Services?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me apologize as I forgot to mention that I was using GWT to program the app.  That being said It seems that the error was coming using the GWT-Ajaxloader library; apparently it must be calling to the api in an antiquated manner.   So the solution for me was to hard code the request into the html
as thus

```
 <!--  The Following proves that picker works with oAuth2 -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
      // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
      function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('picker');
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
```

Once this was done I was able to use the picker object already loaded and put in the setDeveloperKey() method.   Now everything is gravy.  One more caveat...
Make sure that the AccessKey has not expired on the server.   On the Java Api
this can be done by checking when it will expire Credential.getExpiresInSeconds()  I personally gave myself an hour

```
if(cred.getExpiresInSeconds() <= 3600){
   cred.refreshToken();}
```

And this is the fix that has worked for me.